# how does margin affect the Option Price when Selling an Option

Tags: black-scholes, european-options, margin

Currently I'm thinking the effect of margin. When selling an option, you need to pay margin everyday and mark to market. In most exchanges, margin is overcollateralized. But when buying a option, you don't need to pay margin. For an European option, how does margin affect the ask price? Is there any explicate solution for this in *BS framework*?

Any advise or paper is appreciate. Many thanks!

Comment: The margin is also different for itm and otm options, meaning that if you take into account the costs of margin, then calls and outs of the same strike have different considerations, which will break cp parity.

Comment: Not everyone has the same margin rates as well. Large HF will have lower margins then small HF or retail investors

Comment: yes, margin is correlated with moneyness. Is there a way to think about this problem?@will @pyCthon

Comment: I don't see why would margin affect the price? Although you are overcollateralized, you still get interest on your full collateral.

Comment: hi @MainCom, in some market there are no interest for margin, such as China...

Comment: I believe whether you get interest or not does not depend on the market but depends on where the account is setup. Of course most retail investors are not receiving interest.